# How to sort varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

In SQL ( using Access ), I have following values in a column:

Approved,  Point 2, ..., Point 10, Point 11, ..., Point 21

Now, if I used order by `column asc`, Point 11 comes before Point 2. I want Point 2, Point 3 to come before Point 11. How to do it?

Comment: This is because you are performing a _lexicographic sorting_.  What you are looking for is a combined lexicographic and numerical sort.  You would probably have to handle that manually.

Comment: You can still sort it in the WHERE-clause, but you have to split up the text column into text + number, where you pad the number with spaces or zeros.  But you have to devise a scheme to split it up so that it handles values that don't match the "<text><number>" pattern.

Comment: The simplest way, if you are in a position to change the data, would be to add a leading 0 to the single digit values, ie. "Point 2" would become "Point 02".  Obviously this could become unmanageable if you have a lot of records though, having to change "Point 2" to "Point 0002" to get it to come before "Point 1000" might not be desirable.

Comment: I do not have access to change the data but your point is good. Thanks!!!

Comment: @csl : how do you propose to use a WHERE clause to do ay sorting?

Comment: order by IIF(COLUMN_NAME = 'POINT 10','Point 910',COLUMN_NAME) desc works for one point. I guess using LIKE may help. I am not sure if I can use POINT * and then can refer * when converting to Point 9*. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Dems: I mean of course in the ORDER BY, as in ORDER BY some-split-functions(...)

Comment: Your data is stored incorrectly if you need to sort parts of it numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **know** that it's they're always going to be in the form "name number", what you can do is add two columns that are a split that original column , and sort on them instead of the original

e.g.,

```
SELECT foo2.foo, 
    Left(foo,InStr(foo," ")) AS foo_name, 
    CLng(IIf(InStr(foo," ")>0, Right(nz(foo,0),
            Len(nz(foo,0))-InStr(nz(foo,0)," ")),"0")) AS foo_number
FROM foo2
ORDER BY Left(foo,InStr(foo," ")), 
    CLng(IIf(InStr(foo," ")>0, Right(nz(foo,0),
            Len(nz(foo,0))-InStr(nz(foo,0)," ")),"0"));
```

(coded AND tested)

This should give you results like:

```
foo       foo_name  foo_number
---       --------  ----------
Approved  Approved  
Point 2   Point     2
Point 10  Point     10
Point 11  Point     11
Point 21  Point     21
```

and the sorting will work with the foo_number portion.

Comment: To get this to work in Access you need to `Order By` the   `left(foo,InStr(foo," ")), clng(right(foo, len(foo) - instr(foo," ")))` and of course, select `from` something! ;-)

Comment: @ CREsults: Thanks. 
It is showing Data Type Mismatch to me when I try in Order By clause

"clng(right(Session, len(Session) - instr(Session,' ')))"

Comment: Actually you just need to sort by Foo, (although its good for Demo purposes)

Comment: But, the issue is not to sort by Foo and use numbers. Right?

Comment: clng is the cause of Type mismatch. Any idea?

Comment: clng is the cause of Type mismatch. Any idea? I guess, when foo_name = Approved, that is causing the problem as foo_number is perhaps

Comment: the nz()'s are in there just incase someone dumps a null value in there.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - no, but it would handle the "Points 11 A" situation better.

Comment: `ORDER BY 2, 3` looks much nicer to me.

Comment: Val("11 A") gives 11.  CLng("11 A") throws type mismatch error.

Comment: @HansUp - agreed on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and it seems that Access is "smart" enough to know what you want. This is the minimum you need to do.

```
SELECT YourFields
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 
   PointColumn,
   Mid([PointColumn],6)
```

This approach and others like it aren't [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so if you want to filter for records `< Point 10` it will be slow.

So instead I recommend that you normalize your data. Add a field called IsApproved (boolean) and Add another field called point that keeps track of the points

Then its easy to do things like

```
SELECT IIF(IsApproved, "Approved", "Point " & [Point]) as output
FROM 
    table
WHERE
    IsApproved = true or Point < 10
ORDER BY
  IsApproved,
  Point
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about access but if there is a replace function, then you could do something like this(like in sql server):

```
select      *, cast ( replace( replace( pointColumnName, 'Point', ''), 'Approved', 1000) as int )  as points
from        tblName
order       by points
```

where tblName is the table and pointColumnName is the column with your data.

Comment: The Access dialect of SQL doesn't include `replace`--but Access *does* allow you to include (some) VBA functions in your SQL statements (including the VBA `Replace`).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to performance, the usual tricks are two:

1. Sort using `varcharcol, intcol` (varcharcol containing "Point" and intcol containing the number)
2. Add an extra indexed column that contains "Point 000001", "Point 000010", "Point 000020", etc. with enough zeros to accommodate what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For brevity..

```
SELECT * From MyTable
Order By Int(Replace(MyColumn,'Point',''))
```